# Check if computer is locked using VBscript

Tags: vbscript

How can I Check if the Computer has been Locked using VBscript? I want to stop an app from running once the Computer has been locked and run it again when it is unlocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try checking for the existence of the `logonui.exe` process. If you find it, the computer is locked or not logged in.

```
Function IsLocked(strComputer)

    With GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        IsLocked = .ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process where Name='logonui.exe'").Count > 0
    End With

End Function
```

To test the local computer, pass the PC name or a period. For example:

```
If IsLocked(".") Then MsgBox "Local computer is locked."
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried running it but IsLocked is false even when the computer is locked. I use windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Hmm. I'm also on Win7-64 and this works fine for me. I just created a script that calls this function once a second for 10 seconds and wrote the return value to a text file. I then ran the script, locked the computer after a few seconds, then put my password in to unlock the computer. `IsLocked()` returned `True` during the span where I had locked the computer and `False` otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is a reliable method.  If a computer is logged on only via RDP but not at the console, the LogonUI.exe will be running since the console is displaying the logon screen.  However, the RDP session can/will still be active to the remote user who is connected to it.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution for multiple users logged on!
Not working for remote users... solution WIP

```
dim islocked

do
    call checklock
loop while  islocked = 0


'=================================
'Functions
'=================================

function checklock
    Dim computer : computer = "."

    If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
        computer = WScript.Arguments(0)
    End If

    If locked(computer) Then
        msgbox "debugging: locked"  
    Else
        msgbox "debugging: not locked"
        wscript.sleep 3000 'for debugging - allow time to enter lock screen
    End If      
end function


Function locked(computer)
    Dim wmi : Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & computer & "/root/cimv2")
    Dim lockapp_count : lockapp_count = wmi.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'lockapp.exe'").Count
    Dim explorer_count : explorer_count = wmi.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'explorer.exe'").Count
    locked = (lockapp_count >= explorer_count)
End Function
```

Other nitty gritty background:
Solution ISSUE (on machine w/ multiple users)
I was using this for a while until I added another user onto the machine. Now when the OTHER user has locked their screen, even though my screen is active, not locked, the VBS says it's locked, b/c `logonUI.exe` is running - so it throws a false positive. It's also tricky b/c the process is run by the system not by the user so you can't do a cross check. I do wonder though, if you could count the number of `lockapp.exe` processes and compare to the number of `logonui.exe` processes. However - I don't know if they are always one to one.

WIP Solution - this is found to work - yay - solution and code moved to the top of my comment.
Count the number of active users and compare the count to the number of `logonui.exe` processes. To do this I'm trying to count how many times `explorer.exe` is found, then comparing to the number of `logonui.exe` instances.

Failed solution 1:
Compare count of `logonui.exe` to `lockapp.exe` count
Reason - these must go together, i was assuming you'd only ever get 1 logonui process but multiple lockapp processes; wrong assumption.